# asp.net html.TextBox removed the value after post request or load new data

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm fresher in asp.net and I have some issue.
I have a text box of the field firstname

```
  <td>
             <%=Html.TextBox("FirstName", "")%>
             <%=Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Name,"TextBox")%>
        </td>
```

when i make a post request with the server and the the page load again then the value I insert into the firstName removed.
but if I make this way it works good and save the value I bind into the input field.

```
 <%=Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name,"TextBox")%>
```

this way I don't want because I need to create more variables in my model for first name and last name..so i prefer to make it another way.

I tried to declare 2 global variable in javascript and then to bind the data but I can't succeed to use it..
that's what I did

```
<td>
             <%=Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FirstName)%>
             <%=Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Name,"TextBox")%>
        </td>
```

in javascript

```
  var lastName = $('#LastName').val();
        var firstName = $('#FirstName').val();
```

in viewModel i declare

```
 private string _FirstName;
    private string _LastName;
```

Comment: You *should* be making more variables in your *viewmodel*.  This way they are strongly typed - and all the other benefits you get, like post-POST-repopulating (which is what you're missing here).

Comment: yes, but the firstName and lastName I need only for this form. so I thought to declare it as globally in javascript but I not succeed to use it in the textBox to bind it

Comment: You're mixing your server-side and client-side technologies.  Anything in `<%=` can't see any javascript as it's not got there yet.

Comment: You're also mixing your *model* and *viewmodel* usage.   The viewmodel should contain everything you need on your form, and then map to the model in the controller.

Comment: I understand.. so what yo suggest to make? making more variables and use EditorFor or TextBox? because in the Html.TextBox i can't write Html.TextBox("Firstname",model.firstname)

Comment: The suggestion (of course, you don't have to follow it) is that you create a *viewmodel* with firstname/lastname properties and use `@Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.FirstName)`.  it might be slightly more work up-front, but will save you tons of headaches if you follow the simply pattern of controller->viewmodel->view.  Never do `Html.TextBox("Firstname",model.firstname) ` as it won't bind to the model, your post will reset the value each time.

Comment: I declared two variables in the viewModel, how can i get they value in javascript with JQuery? I tried to do  var firstname = $("#FirstName").val();  #FirstName I thought I can make because I did  <%=Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FirstName)%>

Comment: `var firstname = $("#FirstName").val();` should be correct.  Look in the browser inspect-element at your rendered HTML for the ID of the textbox that's generated.

Comment: that's what i did. I checked in the html and it show me the element as input id ="FirstName" but it's not works for me.

Comment: I edited my post you can see what I did without success.

Comment: Not sure why you created your "properties" as private *fields* (and with random underscores).  `public string FirstName { get;set; }`  .  But then `Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m>FirstName)` should have given an error.   The question is - where is your javascript code?  If it's in the `<head>` then the element won't exist yet.  Try running it in the console after the page has loaded.  Do you have jquery loaded?  What error do you get? "without success" is a tad vague.

Comment: actually I don't know what it the error. after I press on the submit form then it shows me page not found because that.. in debugger mode it works good without crashing... really weird....

Answer (score 0):

`Html.TextBox("FirstName", "")` only create input with `<input type="text" value="" />` so you can't save the values when the page refreshed.

If you insisting not to use in model, you need to send the values in your post
save it (in `viewbag` for example) and show the value